# tooltip box jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to set up a user interface with jQuery, a .js scripts loads some data from a binary executable and should present those data into a tooltip box next to the element representing the required source. A html page gives the structure for an extended box for an element as you can see from the image. My problem is that the tooltip pops only for the last source (audio codec 06, which overwrite all other) and I need a tootlip box for every source as it should change his content whenever I drive the mouse on a different source, so a tooltip box for every sources.

[image: tooltip box on source audio codec 6]

here .js file javascript jQuery:

```
 if (ServiceType=='spu.outputs') {
   Mode=json.data["OUTPUT_HANDLING"];
   if ((Mode=="a") || (Mode==2)) {
     Mode=2;
   } else if (Mode=="3") {
     Mode=3;
   } else {
     Mode=1;
   }
 }
 $('#spu_inputs_services').data("Mode"+ServiceID,Mode);
 Context_ServiceID.find('.extended-monitoring').load('html/monitoring/monitoring-'+ServiceType+'-'+Mode+'.html', function() {

            if ((ServiceType=='spu.sources')) {
                console.log ("set tooltip spu.sources");
                    $(this).tooltip({items: "[data]", 
                        content: "<p>test</p>"});
    $.getJSON("../"+ServiceName+"/configedit?cfgName=3.&json=1", function (data) {
            if ((ServiceType=='spu.inputs')) {
                console.log ("dolbyA"+ $(this));
                        $(this).tooltip({items: "[dolbyA]",
                        content: "<p>test dolbyA</p>"});
            }
            if ((ServiceType=='spu.inputs')) {
                console.log ("dolbyB"+$(this));
                        $(this).tooltip({items: "[dolbyB]",
                        content: "<p>test dolbyB</p>"});
            }
            if ((ServiceType=='spu.inputs')) {
                console.log ("dolbyC"+$(this));
                        $(this).tooltip({items: "[dolbyC]",
                        content: "<p>test dolbyC</p>"});
            }
            if ((ServiceType=='spu.inputs')) {
                console.log ("dolbyD"+$(this));
                        $(this).tooltip({items: "[dolbyD]",
                        content: "<p>test dolbyD</p>"});
            }
            if ((ServiceType=='spu.inputs')) {
                console.log ("dolbyE"+$(this));
                        $(this).tooltip({items: "[dolbyE]",
                        content: "<p>test dolbyE</p>"});
            }
            if ((ServiceType=='spu.inputs')) {
                console.log ("dolbyF"+$(this));
                        $(this).tooltip({items: "[dolbyF]",
                        content: "<p>test dolbyF</p>"});
            }
```

html elements:

```
  <div style="clear:both;">
      <div style="float:left">Audio Codec 01</div>
      <div id="AUDIO_CODEC_1" data="dolby" dolbyA="A" style="float:right">n/a</div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;">
      <div style="float:left">Audio Codec 02</div>
      <div id="AUDIO_CODEC_2" data="dolby" dolbyB="B" style="float:right">n/a</div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;">
      <div style="float:left">Audio Codec 03</div>
      <div id="AUDIO_CODEC_3" data="dolby" dolbyC="C" style="float:right">n/a</div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;">
      <div style="float:left">Audio Codec 04</div>
      <div id="AUDIO_CODEC_4" data="dolby" dolbyD="D" style="float:right">n/a</div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;">
      <div style="float:left">Audio Codec 05</div>
      <div id="AUDIO_CODEC_5" data="dolby" dolbyE="E" style="float:right">n/a</div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;">
      <div style="float:left">Audio Codec 06</div>
      <div id="AUDIO_CODEC_6" class="dolby" dolbyF="F" style="float:right">n/a</div>
  </div>
```

the console logs [object Object] for $(this) and undefined for 'id':

[image: Console log]

Comment: it seems that the object jQuery constructs with the $(this) command is alwas the same. try `console.log($(this))` in your condition blocks. also, do your current `console.log` commands generate output as expected?

Comment: could you post the entire function in which you have the js code. we need to know $(this) who is refering to

Comment: I also used the variation `(ServiceType=='spu.inputs') && $(this).attr('id') == 'AUDIO_CODEC_1`it does not seems to find anything.

Comment: the object contructed whit $(this) is the same for all sources. I need something to get the IDs.

Comment: i took the liberty to do some formatting. i also found there was a (faulty) semicolon at the end of the `if (ServiceType=='spu.outputs') { }` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found an elegant solution for this problem, hope it can help other jQuery freaks:

```
        console.log ("dolby "+ServiceType+'-'+ServiceID+'-'+Mode+$(this).html());
        $(this).find("div[dolby]").each(function() {
            console.log ("dolby 2 "+ServiceType+'-'+ServiceID+'-'+Mode+$(this).html()+$(this).attr("dolby"));
            $(this).tooltip({items: "[dolby]", content: "<p>test dolby "+$(this).attr("dolby")+"</p>"});
            }
        });
```

I also accordingly changed the .html file where i'am loading the information from:

```
 <div style="clear:both;">
      <div style="float:left">Audio Codec 01</div>
      <div id="AUDIO_CODEC_1" data="dolby" dolby="1" style="float:right">n/a</div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;">
      <div style="float:left">Audio Codec 02</div>
      <div id="AUDIO_CODEC_2" data="dolby" dolby="2" style="float:right">n/a</div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;">
      <div style="float:left">Audio Codec 03</div>
      <div id="AUDIO_CODEC_3" data="dolby" dolby="3" style="float:right">n/a</div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;">
      <div style="float:left">Audio Codec 04</div>
      <div id="AUDIO_CODEC_4" data="dolby" dolby="4" style="float:right">n/a</div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;">
      <div style="float:left">Audio Codec 05</div>
      <div id="AUDIO_CODEC_5" data="dolby" dolby="5" style="float:right">n/a</div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;">
      <div style="float:left">Audio Codec 06</div>
      <div id="AUDIO_CODEC_6" data="dolby" dolby="6" style="float:right">n/a</div>
```